# How to locate a list element (Selenium)?

Tags: java, list, xpath, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
<li> item1 is red
</li>
<li> item1 is blue 
</li>
<li> item1 is white  
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried the following to print the first item:

```
String item = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[0]")).getText();
        System.out.println(item);
```

However, I got: NoSuchElementException...
I could use a cssSelector but I do not have the id for the ul

Comment: @fredrik has the right answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the XPath should be `"//ul/li[1]"`. In selenium the first item is 1, not 0. Look [here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Help+With+XPath)

Comment: +1 This is a common problem for programmers trained in C-based languages.  XPath counts from 1, not 0.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not as efficient as the other answer but I think it gives you the result.

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('li').first()");

String item = element.getText()
```

Comment: Not going to downvote this because it will work, but you are playing a dangerous game: you are assuming that jQuery is loaded. jQuery is not a standard.

Answer (score 2):

```
(//ul/li)[1]
```

**This selects the first in the XML document `li` element that is a child of a `ul` element**.

**Do note that the expression**:

```
//ul/li[1]
```

selects any `li` element that is the first child of its `ul` parent. Thus this expression in general may select more than one element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it:

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul li"));
if ( items.size() > 0 ) {
  for ( WebElement we: items ) {
   System.out.println( we.getText() );
  }
}
```